# How to update multiple core data attribute in swift 2

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, multiple-columns, insert-update

I want to update multiple attributes of an entity using swift but couldn't find any tutorial to manage that. I've managed to update single attribute of an entity with the below code :

```
   //Insert Function
func Insert(dbname : String , attributeName : String , value : String ) {
    let check_empty = entityIsEmpty(dbname)
    if(check_empty != true){

    let saveData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(dbname, inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    // add our data
    saveData.setValue(value, forKey: attributeName)

    //2
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //3
        check_DB.append(saveData)

    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    //check_empty
}else{
        //Update procedure
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: dbname)

        do {
            let fetchedEntities = try self.managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [SettingInfo]
            fetchedEntities.first?.attributeName = value

            // ... Update additional properties with new values
        } catch {
            // Do something in response to error condition
        }

        do {
            try self.managedContext.save()

        } catch {
            // Do something in response to error condition
        }

}
```

}

but how can I update multiple attributes of an entity ? 
for example : Entity name is : `dbname` 
Attribute name is : `attribute`_name 
And the value of the attribute which i want to update is : `value`

UPDATE : 
error message : [image]

My database structure : 
[image]

Comment: Just update the other attributes in the same way as you did the first. What is the problem? Instead of fetching the object, updating and saving in one function, have a function that returns the object, the update all of the attributes and then save it in another function

Comment: my problem is this function is not recognizing dbname and it's attributes ,as you can see they are function arguments , if i put them constant it works. right now with the above code i get error of dbname is not a type and it doesn't recognize attribute name

Comment: @Paulw11 you suggest to have 3 functions to do the job ? each one do single operation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyed access to NSManagedEntities, so you can say

```
if let entity = fetchedEntities.first {
    entity[attribute_name]=value
}
```

Comment: You can't use `as [dbname]` because `dbname` is a variable that contains your entity name.  The fetch request will return `[NSManagedObject]`. Your image doesn't show the function signature, so I can't say what you code should say, but `attribute_name` isn't a known variable, so what do you have in the function parameter list?

Comment: Thanks for answering , this is what i have in function parameter list : func update(dbname : string, attribute_name :string , value : string)

Comment: from that `attribute_name` looks correct.  _ are ugly and perhaps you have a unicode character if you have copied/pasted it.  Change it to the more conventional `attributeName`

Comment: Ok now i update my code above and the new error that i get. I want to update the first row of each attribute and if it's empty insert one into attribute.

Comment: Yes, you can't use `.attributeName` since there is no property on NSManagedObject of `attributeName`  You have to use `[attributeName]` since you want to use the variable as the key

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with the following code :

```
//Update procedure
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: dbname)

                do {
                    let fetchedEntities = try self.managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [SettingInfo]
                    let attribute = fetchedEntities[0] as NSManagedObject
                    attribute.setValue(value , forKey: attributeName)

                    // ... Update additional properties with new values
                } catch {
                    // Do something in response to error condition
                }

                do {
                    try self.managedContext.save()

                } catch {
                    // Do something in response to error condition
                }
```